# How can i Connect struts-config.1-3.10.dtd file my struts-config.xml

Tags: struts-config

I am a beginner to struts.I am getting a error i never heard in classroom.The error is in struts-config.xml.The code for it is

```
    <!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC     
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN"     "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">    
<struts-config><form-beans>    
<form-bean name="form1" type="LoginForm"/>    
</form-beans><action-mappings>    
<action path="/LoginAction" name="form1" type="LoginAction"/>    
<forward name="success" path="/success.jsp"/>    
<forward name="failuer" path="/Failure.jsp"/   
</action>    
</action-mappings>    
</struts-config>
```

Now the problem at `<!DOCTYPE>` tag and di
splaying the following error

"The download of the specified resource has failed. Error processing resource

```
'http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1...
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">"
```

While trying to fix this error i download the `.dtd` file from http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-core/dtddoc/struts-config_1_3.dtd.org.html
and saved it.In `struts-config.xml`, i tried to locate place where i save downloaded file 
but is not working.
What should i do to fix this problem.Where i went wrong.Any response will be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the downloaded `"struts-config_1_3.dtd"` file in WEB-INF folder.

Also from struts-config.xml in DOCTYPE tag replace the following

```
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC     
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN"     "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">


with 


<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC     
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN" "struts-config_1_3.dtd">
```